# Highcharts chart not displaying data from csv file

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on a project that is supposed to take csv data that is being written in real time and display it on an html page. I am using Javascript, and the JQuery, HighCharts, and PapaParse libraries.

Here is my JSFiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/m5n8xdo9/3/

I know it doesn't look right, but I don't know how to make it look like it looks on my computer. Should I use a different hosting site?

When I hardcode dummy data into the chart like this:

```
//Altitude
    $(function () {
        $('#altGraph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Payload Altitude'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Altitude (m) vs. Time (s)'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Altitude (m)'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Altitude',
                data: //dummy data here
            }]
        });
    });
```

it all works and looks nice. But when I use papaparse to parse the csv into arrays of data, and pass an array of data to the corresponding chart like so:

```
//Altitude
    $(function () {
        $('#altGraph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Payload Altitude'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Altitude (m) vs. Time (s)'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Altitude (m)'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Altitude',
                data: altitude
            }]
        });
    });
```

the charts show up blank.

On my computer, after you choose a file the charts show up, though empty of data points. That's my problem. I was thinking that maybe since the charts are written to the page before the data is uploaded, that would be why the data isn't showing up. I am currently at a loss as to how to fix this.

Comment: So all you are changing is the `altitude` data? Then please provide an example of how that data looks. Also, anything in console?

Comment: the example data is in the jsfiddle link. The altitude data should come from a csv file, and not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your papaParse convert values to strings in array, instead of numbers. See "dynamicTyping" parameter and then set it as true.